# cupy/numpy ignores duplicate indexes

Tags: python, numpy, cupy

When we uses arrays as indexes cupy/numpy ignores duplicates.
Example:

```
import cupy as cp

matrix = cp.zeros((3, 3))
xi = cp.asarray([0, 1, 1, 2])
yi = cp.asarray([0, 1, 1, 2])
matrix[xi, yi] += 1
print(matrix.get())
```

Output:

```
[[1. 0. 0.]
 [0. 1. 0.]
 [0. 0. 1.]]
```

Desired output:

```
[[1. 0. 0.]
 [0. 2. 0.]
 [0. 0. 1.]]
```

The second one (1, 1) index is ignored. How to apply operation for duplicate indexes also?

Comment: ufuncs (see np.add.reduce) are made for that but AFAIK they are slow for 2D cases (also for 1D case currently, but we plan to speed up this soon).

Comment: Look at `np.add.at`

Comment: Thanx, hpaulj. np.add.at - works fine for numpy. The same method for cupy is cupyx.scatter_add.